# Why does this parser always fail when the end-of-line sequence is CRLF?

Tags: haskell, attoparsec, end-of-line

This simple parser is expected to parse messages of the form

```
key: value\r\nkey: value\r\n\r\nkey: value\r\nkey: value\r\n\r\n
```

One EOL acts as a field separator, and double EOL acts as a message separator. It works perfectly fine when the EOL separator is `\n` but `parseWith` always returns fail when it is `\r\n`.

```hs
parsePair = do
  key <- B8.takeTill (==':')
  _ <- B8.char ':'
  _ <- B8.char ' '
  value <- B8.manyTill B8.anyChar endOfLine
  return (key, value)

parseListPairs = sepBy parsePair endOfLine <* endOfLine

parseMsg = sepBy parseListPairs endOfLine <* endOfLine
```

Comment: Where did you get `endOfLine` from, or how did you define it? What does `B8` stand for? I can make an educated guess, but still... You need to make the code in your question self-contained, by adding your import statements and custom definitions. The problem is probably that `endOfLine` is defined to parse `\n`, not `\r\n`. You will have to define your own `endOfLine` parser for `\r\n`.

Comment: @Jubobs Probably not. Chances are this is [attoparsec's `endOfLine`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.0.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#v:endOfLine).

Comment: @duplode You're right, but the relevant link is probably [this one](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.0.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-Char8.html#g:13), as suggested by the name `B8`.

Comment: endOfLine is from [Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.0.1/docs/src/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-Internal.html#endOfLine]%28Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8%29) I checked the implementation and it handles both end lines.

Comment: You need to clarify. You state that one EOL acts as a pair separator, and two EOLs act as a message separator, but your example (`key: value\r\nkey: value\r\n\r\n`) suggests that two EOLs act as a message *terminator*, instead. Separator would make more sense to me, but which is it? Separator, or terminator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using these imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8 as B8
import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8
```

The problem is that `endOfLine` consumes the end of line, so perhaps you really want something like:

```
parseListPairs = B8.many1 parsePair <* endOfInput
```

For instance, this works:

```
ghci> parseOnly parseListPairs "k: v\r\nk2: v2\r\n"
Right [("k","v"),("k2","v2")]
```

Update:

For parsing multiple messages you can use:

```
parseListPairs = B8.manyTill parsePair endOfLine
parseMsgs = B8.manyTill parseListPairs endOfInput

ghci> test3 = parseOnly parseMsgs "k1: v1\r\nk2: v2\r\n\r\nk3: v3\r\nk4: v4\r\n\r\n"
Right [[("k1","v1"),("k2","v2")],[("k3","v3"),("k4","v4")]]
```

Comment: This is definitely better, but it still fails at some point, I need to revise the structure and do some tests.

Comment: `parseOnly parseMsgs "k: v"` fails, but should yield `Right [[("k","v")]]`.

Answer (score 2):

## Problems

Your code isn't self-contained and the actual problem is unclear. However, I suspect your woes are actually caused by how keys are parsed; in particular, something like `\r\nk` is a valid key, according to your parser:

```
λ> parseOnly parsePair "\r\nk: v\r\n"
Right ("\r\nk","v")
```

That needs to be fixed.

Moreover, since one EOL *separates* (rather than *terminates*) key-value pairs, an EOL shouldn't be consumed at the end of your `parsePair` parser.

Another tangential issue: because you use the `many1` combinator instead `ByteString`-oriented parsers (such as `takeTill`), your values have type `String` instead of `ByteString`. That's probably *not* what you want, here, because it defeats the purpose of using `ByteString` in the first place.; see [Performance considerations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.0.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#g:3).

## Solution

I suggest the following refactoring:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.ByteString ( ByteString )

import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8 ( Parser
                                        , count
                                        , endOfLine
                                        , parseOnly
                                        , sepBy
                                        , string
                                        , takeTill
                                        )

-- convenient type synonyms
type KVPair = (ByteString, ByteString)
type Msg = [KVPair]

pair :: Parser KVPair
pair = do
    k <- key
    _ <- string ": "
    v <- value
    return (k, v)
  where
    key     = takeTill (\c -> c == ':' || isEOL c)
    value   = takeTill isEOL
    isEOL c = c == '\n' || c == '\r'

-- one EOL separates key-value pairs
msg :: Parser Msg
msg = sepBy pair endOfLine

-- two EOLs separate messages
msgs :: Parser [Msg]
msgs = sepBy msg (count 2 endOfLine)
```

I have renamed your parsers, for consistency with `attoparsec`'s, none of which have "parse" as a prefix:

- `parsePair` --> `pair`
- `parseListPairs` --> `msg`
- `parseMsg` --> `msgs`

## Tests in GHCi

```
λ> parseOnly keyValuePair  "\r\nk: v"
Left "string"
```

Good; you do want a fail, in this case.

```
λ> parseOnly keyValuePair  "k: v"
Right ("k","v")

λ> parseOnly msg "k: v\r\nk2: v2\r\n"
Right [("k","v"),("k2","v2")]

λ> parseOnly msgs  "k1: v1\r\nk2: v2\r\n\r\nk3: v3\r\nk4: v4"
Right [[("k1","v1"),("k2","v2")],[("k3","v3"),("k4","v4")]]

λ> parseOnly msgs "k: v"
Right [[("k","v")]]
```

Comment: I understand the performance consideration, my initial implementation was using Bytestring `parsePair :: Parser (ByteString,ByteString)` and takeTill/takeWhile combinators, actually it was very similar to the one you provided, it also failed but I couldn't find the problem, and I posted a different version, now after I saw your impl I suspect my problem was in the definition of isEndOfLine

Comment: I ended up with infinite loop, same result as my original implementation, I will try to figure out the problem. There is also a concern that I am reading from socket. this implementation worked fine with parseOnly the first time.

Comment: @concept3d Just curious: have you made any progress on this?

Comment: this solution still goes into infinite loop when used with parseWith, similar to my original solution which I didn't post. I used the accepted answer temporarily, I'll get back to this soon but I have to finish more important things first.

Comment: @concept3d Ok. I don't think I can investigate any further until I see your code that uses `parseWith`. Good luck.